# How to download two newest .xml files from website in Java

Tags: java, xml

I need to create method, which can download 2 newest .xml files (or just extract URL to these files) from this website:
http://rss.nbp.pl/kursy/xml2/2015/a/. I know how to do it with speciefied URL, but I have no idea how to automatically download newest files.

Actually I've got this:

```
    URL website = new URL(xmlFileUrl);
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("src/com/sh00x/files/kursy2.xml");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Thanks for any help,
Greetings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java Check out @BalusC response on JSoup

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out.

Comment: You can use [Xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361263/library-to-query-html-with-xpath-in-java#answer-14188344) with something like `//a[contains(., '.xml')][position() >= last() - 1]` to get the two last (rows) XML url