# Java HTML XPath selector

Tags: java, html, xpath

I am trying to find a library like C# `htmlagilitypack` for java to parse **HTML** and select elements using XPath.

I have read about many libraries but none of them is standalone XPath selector for HTML, all the libraries that I have found require to parse HTML using their methods like `htmlunit`.

If someone can guide me with a simple example for XPath 2.0 or 3.0 and HTML parsing I would appreciate it.

Comment: Selenium works with selecting xpathes from html

Comment: I am looking for a library to input a html string and use xpath selectors. Selenium needs to open browser.

Comment: Did you try : https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup .It supports XPath 1.0 and has  some other built-in functions.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't support xpath 2.0 or 3.0

Comment: Saxon-HE 's s9api seems the way to go then.

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example ? I can’t find how it works for HTML.

Comment: For htmlunit you can use a html string as input (see FAQ) to get the page and then work with XPath.

Comment: @Heopas is your question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Java has support for [Xpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).   Usually, it used for parsing XML files. However, it should work for HTML as well.

***HTML sample:***

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <br/>
    <h1>Hello <span id="my-demo">User!</span></h1>
    <br/>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/acloudguru-opsworkslab/ACG_Austin.JPG" alt="photo"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Code snippet:***

```
public class HtmlXpathParser {
    private DocumentBuilder builder;
    private XPath path;

    public HtmlXpathParser() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builder = dbfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        XPathFactory xpfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        path = xpfactory.newXPath();
    }

    public Optional<String> parse(String fileName) throws SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
        File file = new File(fileName);

        Document doc = builder.parse(file);
        String result = path.evaluate("//img/@src", doc);

        return Optional.of(result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException, SAXException, IOException {
        HtmlXpathParser parser = new HtmlXpathParser();

        Optional<String> srcResult = parser.parse("src/main/resources/index.html");
        srcResult.ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

***Output:***

> https://s3.amazonaws.com/acloudguru-opsworkslab/ACG_Austin.JPG

It works for XPath version 1. You could use something like [xpath2-parser](https://github.com/exquery/xpath2-parser) if you will need it.

***Useful references:***

- [Intro to XPath with Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath)
- [Library to query HTML with XPath in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361263/library-to-query-html-with-xpath-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer.
The first issue that I see is that this code doesn't' t clean bad HTML and the second is that it doesn't support xpath 3.