# Using XPath Contains against HTML in Java

Tags: java, xpath, html-parsing

I'm scraping values from HTML pages using XPath inside of a java program to get to a specific tag and occasionally using regular expressions to clean up the data I receive.

After some research, I landed on HTML Cleaner ( http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/ ) as the most reliable way to parse raw HTML into a good XML format. HTML Cleaner, however, only supports XPath 1.0 and I find myself needing functions like 'contains'. for instance, in this piece of XML:

```
<div>
  <td id='1234 foo 5678'>Hello</td>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to get the text 'Hello' with the following XPath:

```
//div/td[contains(@id, 'foo')]/text()
```

Is there any way to get this functionality?  I have several ideas, but would prefer not to reinvent the wheel if I don't need to:

- If there is a way to call HTML Cleaner's evaluateXPath and return a TagNode (which I have not found), I can use an XML serializer on the returned TagNode and chain together XPaths to achieve the desired functionality.
- I could use HTML Cleaner to clean to XML, serialize it back to a string, and use that with another XPath library, but I can't find a good java XPath evaluator that works on a string.
- Using TagNode functions like getElementsByAttValue, I could essentially recreate XPath evaluation and insert in the contains functionality using String.contains

Short question: Is there any way to use XPath contains on HTML inside an existing Java Library?

Comment: `contains` is in XPath 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains

Comment: I should have been more specific- HTML cleaner uses a subset of XPath 1.0 that does not allow contains.

Comment: My take is that the developers of HTMLCleaner wasted a lot of time writing a completely unnecessary (and non-compliant) XPath implementation. There's no reason to ever use it. See my answer for a complete example.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Regarding this:

> I could use HTML Cleaner to clean to XML, serialize it back to a
>   string, and use that with another XPath library, but I can't find a
>   good java XPath evaluator that works on a string.

This is *exactly* what I would do (except you don't need to operate on a string (see below)).

A lot of HTML parsers **try to do too much**. HTMLCleaner, for example, does not properly/completely implement the XPath 1.0 spec (`contains` (for example) *is* [an XPath 1.0 function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains)). The good news is that you don't need it to. All you need from HTMLCleaner is for it to parse the malformed input. Once you've done that, it's better to **use the standard XML interfaces** to deal with the resulting (now well-formed) document.

First convert the document into a standard `org.w3c.dom.Document` like this:

```
TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(
        "<div><table><td id='1234 foo 5678'>Hello</td>");
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = new DomSerializer(
        new CleanerProperties()).createDOM(tagNode);
```

And then use the standard JAXP interfaces to query it:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String str = (String) xpath.evaluate("//div//td[contains(@id, 'foo')]/text()", 
                       doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

Comment: That actually works.  Sadly, no maven repo for HtmlCleaner, but the jar is here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlcleaner/?source=typ_redirect

Comment: It (HtmlCleaner) is in maven central. https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner%22%20AND%20a%3A%22htmlcleaner%22

Comment: But I would still like to evaluate XPath 2.0, which is not possible with JAXP.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work with Java 11 and I get `DomSerializer cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: I tried above solution too but did not get any luck. same error what you got. Did you get any solution .