# How to parse html with xpath?

Tags: java, xpath, java-11, htmlcleaner

I ran into a few questions on StackOverflow that asked about parsing html with xpath using Java.

This is the best answer I found so far [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022421/492015).

But it looks like `DomSerializer` is no longer available in Java 11.

How can I use `DomSerializer` in Java 11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below dependency to the `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlcleaner</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Or**

You can download `htmlcleaner-2.6.1.jar` from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/htmlcleaner/htmlcleaner/2.6.1/).

That jar (or artifact) has the `DomSerializer` class within it.

Link to read docs : `http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/DomSerializer.html`