# Extract content using xpath from an HTML doc using pure Java

Tags: java, html, xpath

I want to extract content from an HTML using xpaths using Java. In ruby I can do this using nokogiri as shown here.

```
xpath = '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/p'  
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('test_001_html64.html'))  
doc.xpath().each do |link|  
puts link.content  
end
```

I want to do it in pure Java. I looked at Jsoup but I couldn't find any documentation or example that uses an xpath to do this. Can someone suggest a way?

Thanks

Comment: Many related / duplicates of this question - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022140/using-xpath-contains-against-html-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352594/querying-an-html-page-with-xpath-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361263/library-to-query-html-with-xpath-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net) for that task.

Here's a simple example:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage startPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com/");
List<DomNode> nodes = page.getByXPath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/p");
for (DomNode node : nodes) {
    System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it with [JAXP](http://jaxp.java.net/) (bundled in Java): [JAXP Manual](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/)

Answer (score -2):

You can easily do this in jsoup.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("test_001_html64.html").get();
Elements info = doc.getElementsByTag("html");
//iterate recursively to the desired location in the dom tree.
```

For faster parsing, you can use specific tags/ ids.

The documentation for jsoup (jsoup.org/apidocs) also exists.

Comment: jsoup does not provides an xpath mechanism, but offers a more convenient way.https://norrisshelton.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/jsoup-java-html-parser

Comment: The question is tagged with `xpath`.